# Run macro when on Worksheet change (i.e. changing sheets, not data within sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 20+ worksheets.  Each worksheet has data I'm inputting, separated by tons of columns.  There are three categories I need to fill in, e.g. "Name", "Date", and "Comments".  Instead of having to scroll right/left on each sheet to find "Name", "date", etc. I am thinking to instead create a named range for these three categories, when that sheet is selected.

I do *not* need to trigger this NamedRange macro when a cell changes on a worksheet, rather I need it to run when the worksheet itself changes.  (So, I don't think `Private Sub Worksheet_Change()` is what I want, I don't need to monitor each cell within the worksheet.  Just want to know if the sheet itself changes.)

The only other option is to add the code to *each worksheet*, using `Worksheet_Activate`.  However, I'd have to go in and add code to 20+ sheets, is that the only way?  I'm sure I'm forgetting something...

The macro would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
On Error Resume Next
' Delete the named ranges that exist, so you can reset
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names 
    if nm = "Name" or nm = "Date" or nm = "Comment" Then nm.Delete 
Next nm
On Error Goto 0
ws.names.add Name:="Date", RefersTo:=ws.Range("A1")
ws.names.add Name:="Name", RefersTo:=ws.Range("KK1")
ws.names.add Name:="Comment", RefersTo:=ws.Range("ZZ1")
End Sub
```

So the idea is that when I activate a new sheet, it clears the current "Name"/"Date"/"Comment" named range, resets it to refer to the active sheet's addresses.  This way I can just quickly use the formula bar dropdown to go to the named range.

Any ideas other than putting the above code in *each* worksheet?  I tried putting it in `ThisWorkbook` but it doesn't do anything.  What am I not considering?

Comment: `Workbook_SheetActivate` maybe?

Comment: @Warcupine - Aha, that works! If I use `Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` in `ThisWorkbook`.  Perfect! If you create an answer, I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh as object)`

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetactivate

Answer (score 0):

```
'put this sub in ThisWorkbook module (is workbook's event)

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   Call onActivate(Sh)
End Sub


'and this in a module
Public Sub onActivate(ws As Worksheet)
   Dim nm As Excel.Name
   On Error Resume Next
   ' Delete the named ranges that exist, so you can reset
   For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
       If nm = "Name" Or nm = "Date" Or nm = "Comment" Then nm.Delete
   Next nm
   On Error GoTo 0
   ws.Names.Add Name:="Date", RefersTo:=ws.Range("A1")
   ws.Names.Add Name:="Name", RefersTo:=ws.Range("KK1")
   ws.Names.Add Name:="Comment", RefersTo:=ws.Range("ZZ1")
End Sub
```